# Ground versus negative terminal in a data sheet

Tags: ground

In the following [datasheet](http://files.pepperl-fuchs.com/selector_files/navi/productInfo/edb/104092_eng.pdf).

At some point it says : "If the option for synchronization is not used, the synchronization input has to be connected to **ground (0 V)** or the sensor must be operated via a V1 cordset (4-pin). The synchronization function cannot be activated during programming mode and vice versa."

Is ground (O V) same with -Ub (negative terminal of the power supply)? I'm kind of confused why they use different terminology.

Comment: It can be a bit confusing; in this case, the two terms appear to be equivalent.

Comment: Friend, need make synchronize if you use more than one sensor. And your question : Ground is -V of source voltage,(ground not  Earth !)

Comment: For such a device & question you should be able to talk to the FSE (Field Service Engineer) from that company.  I see the phone numbers on the bottom of the data sheet.